# Why Holika died inside fire, in spite of a boon?

Tags: festivals, boon, prahlada

King Hiranyakashipu tried many ways to kill his son Prahlada. Holika was his sister with a boon that a fire can not burn/harm her.

To kill Prahlada in fire, Hiranyakashipu asked her sister's help. She suggested that she will sit in fire with Prahlada in her lap, so this way the fire will burn the Prahlada.

Now when the fire was finished, Holika was burned into fire while nothing has happened to Prahlada.

So, My question is Why Holika got burned in fire even when she was having a boon not to get burned in the fire? In other words why the boon didn't work?

[image: Image of Prahlada sitting in the lap of Holika in fire.]

<sup>[Topic of this week is holi](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/363/467)</sup>

Comment: I don't think Holika is mentioned in Hindu scripture at all.  It may just be a folklore addition to the story of Prahlada.

Comment: Please don't create unnecessary tags, lets not get too specific of what we are asking

Comment: Holika was not aware that the boon will work only when she was alone in the fire.

Comment: Holika died in the fire because Lord Vishnu had rescued Prahallada form that fire.

Comment: Could you mention the boon exactly word to word in your question that might help to get the loop hole in her boon. Since gods always leave a loophole in boons to kill asuras.

Comment: The boon was the blanket that she had to wear to protect herself from fire, but bcoz of divine power(wind) that blanket came over prahalad's body. Hence she burnt dead.

Comment: Very Simple the sari was given for good deeds and not for destroying a life
the reason Holika died in the fire and the Lord saved his devotee.

Answer (score -1):

Holika's boon was that fire won't burn her, if she (only her) uses the magical shawal. While trying to burn Prahlad, she used the shawal but its not just her its also the Prahlad who was present, so that voilated the condition of the boon and hence died.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism! Do add some [references and citations to confirm the accuracy of your answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/793/4459). Note that we have a strict [Back it up!](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2/4459) rule on this site. Do go through the [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/4459). Good luck!

Comment: Pls add references. I downvoted your post.