# Why did not demons think of burning only prahlad (without holika) on fire?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, prahlada

I am watching Shri Krishna, story of holika and prahlad, Is the story true? Why did holika with prahlad on fire? I cannot believe that Demons were that dumb, that they did not think of burning only prahlad (without holika) on fire?

Please enlighten me!

P.S. I am true believer of Hinduism (tark ke saath vishvaas i.e. belief with proof)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do women observe Holika vrata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33943/why-do-women-observe-holika-vrata)

Comment: Between, Welcome to the Hinduism SE!

Comment: @Vivikta No, the above talks more about the same myth but not anything about why did she took prahlad on his lap before burning.

Comment: Demons have tried to kill Prahlada many times but he survived every time..Holika had the boon (the power) to resist fire so idea was picked as Holika will not allow Prahlada to escape from fire till he dies...

Comment: @YDS , I think with the new edit, this question has now become Opinion-Based. Also, as far as I recall with my limited knowledge, [there's no mention of a detailed story of Holika](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6595/why-holika-died-inside-fire-in-spite-of-a-boon?rq=1) in any other text beside the Narada Purana, which again is very brief. The detailed story as is generally shown these days on TV might be derived from folklore and hearsay or the sthala or non-extant texts.

Answer (score 1):

Initially Hiranyakashipu did throw Prahalad into the fire, but that was of no use, then after repeated attempts, His sister Holika wanted to help Hiranyakashipu in killing his child, Holika has a fire shielding shawl which she wrapped around herself and made Prahalad sit on her lap and when the fire was breaking Screaming voices were heard( the demons thought it was Prahalad as (children used to have smooth voices like women),when the fire was done Prahalad was seen praying Narayana and was covered with the shawl whereas Holika was burnt to death, So I hope you got it now, yep Demons are not soo foolish they have tried sooo many times but none worked

P.S- this was the story I heard from my elders and wikipedia mentions it [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holika#:~:text=Holika%20had%20a%20special%20cloak,death%2C%20Prahlad%20came%20out%20unharmed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holika#:%7E:text=Holika%20had%20a%20special%20cloak,death%2C%20Prahlad%20came%20out%20unharmed).
But I don't know the book that mentions regarding Holika, Sriad Bhagavatham doesn't mention anything regarding Holika in Prahalada Charitra

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. Is this documented somewhere? I could not find any.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holika#:~:text=Holika%20had%20a%20special%20cloak,death%2C%20Prahlad%20came%20out%20unharmed. This was the story I heard from my elders, But still I have read Sri Bhagavatham which does mention about Prahalad Charitra But I didn't find any info regarding Holika